# What does the numeric prefix mean for the files located in `/etc/sudoers.d`?

Tags: linux, sudo

I go to `/etc/sudoers` folder to check users who have sudo permission and found each file has a numeric prefix.

```
root@10.0.1.13:/etc/sudoers.d# ls
80-deploy-user  90-cloud-init-users README
```

What are they used for?

Comment: The files are read in alphabetical order.  The numeric prefix sets the order that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are read in alphabetical order. The numeric prefix sets the order that way. - user10489

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained in `man run-parts`. `run-parts` is a tool for orderly processing of a bunch o' files (data, rules, definitions, etc), when you don't know all the filenames in advance. This allows for easier configuration management. All the software tools that use `run-parts` follow the same configuration file ordering. `run-parts` is an alternative to the "one giant config file" approach. 1GCF makes it more difficult to be sure one has found (and fixed) all the config entries one needs to. With `run-parts`, all of the config entries dealing with a single topic can be stored in a single dedicated file. The order imposed by `run-parts` makes it possible to "do" one part before or after another, which is handy, sometimes.